# Make debugger in Nextjs point to actual file and not minified file

Tags: reactjs, next.js, deployment, vercel

I'm trying to deploy via Vercel and on build I get a `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')` pointing to `Array.map <anonymous>` although npm run dev works fine. During debugging, the error points to a file called `.next\server\chunks\755.js:1:2128` and a minified file in node-modules called `node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:59:44)`. Is there a way to get the debugger to point to where the error is in the actual component file? Working with NextJS and React.